# Specify binding for HeaderTemplate programmatically

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, tabcontrol, attachedbehaviors

I'm having various problems with the virtualisation of views in the `TabControl`. Luckily, I've found something that I think will solve all my problems in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362940/Persist-the-Visual-Tree-when-switching-tabs-in-t).

One problem is introduced by this solution though, and that is that it destroys my `HeaderTemplate`. The tab header has the same content as the content control.

My view uses a TabControl like this:

```
<TabControl
        behaviors:TabItemGeneratorBehavior.ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=OneWay}"
        behaviors:TabItemGeneratorBehavior.SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

The `behaviors:TabItemGeneratorBehavior` is from the CodeProject article. Inside the `TabItemGeneratorBehavior` is a method that generates `TabItems`:

```
private void AddTabItem(object item)
{
    var contentControl = new ContentControl();
    var tab = new TabItem
        {
            DataContext = item,
            Content = contentControl,
            HeaderTemplate = _tabControl.ItemTemplate
        };

    contentControl.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding());
    tab.SetBinding(HeaderedContentControl.HeaderProperty, new Binding());

    _tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

I think my problem is with the line that sets the binding for the `HeaderProperty`. How can I set the binding so that it uses the `HeaderTemplate` defined in my XAML above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

The solution is to remove the `HeaderTemplate` assignment when creating the `TabItem`:

```
var tab = new TabItem
    {
        DataContext = item,
        Content = contentControl,
        // HeaderTemplate = _tabControl.ItemTemplate
    };
```